# Issue With Distinct Count SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am having an issue getting the count in a query of mine. I have a query that I am trying to see how many people are assigned to each car model.

I would like the data to be returned like so :

```
Car Model     People

Accord        5
Malibu        6
Model S       4
```

Right now I am getting this with the query that I have :

```
Car Model     People

Accord        15
Malibu        15
Model S       15
```

There are a total of 15 people and I am getting that in return rather than a distinct count for each model.. I will post query below:

```
  SELECT b.[ModelName], COUNT(DISTINCT a.[CustomerID])
  FROM firstTable a
  left join secondTable b on b.[ModelID] = a.[ModelID]    
  WHERE [Country] = 'US'
  GROUP BY b.[ModelName]
```

Comment: Could you post the data in the 2 tables?

Comment: Can you post the tables structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `left join` and are counting from the *first* table.  You want to count from the second:

```
  SELECT b.[ModelName], COUNT(DISTINCT b.[ModelId])
  FROM firstTable a LEFT JOIN
       secondTable b
       on b.[ModelID] = a.[ModelID]    
  WHERE [Country] = 'US'
  GROUP BY b.[ModelName]
```

However, it is quite suspicious that you are aggregating by the model name in the *second* table, because it can be `NULL`.  You might also just want a `RIGHT JOIN` in your first query (actually, I would reverse the tables and still use `LEFT JOIN`).

Comment: I must be missing something, but even if op was counting from the first table, unless s/he was using a `CROSS JOIN` s/he shouldn't get the results that are posted

Comment: @Lamak . . . Good observation.  I can't think of a way to arrange the data to get the results in the question.  I suspect something is missing from the OP's query.